# The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'React')

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, react-native, azure-devops

i change my iOS deployment target version 12 but still  i getting below error 
AzureDevops " The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1."

❌  error: No profiles for 'ios.kapiling' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'ios.kapiling'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'community_app')

❌  error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/community_app-fhymwcmnzwnuwactrmznowzhpgqo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/community_app/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libReact.a':

```
The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'React')
The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'RNGestureHandler')
The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'AirMaps')
The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'RNImageRotate')
The iOS deployment target is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'GoogleUtilities')
The iOS deployment target is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'nanopb')
The iOS deployment target is set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement')
The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'Protobuf')
The iOS deployment target is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions for this platform is 8.0 to 12.1. (in target 'ReactNativeFingerprintScanner')
```

Comment: Any updates or solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem on my local environment updating my react libraries and then updating the pods.

```
yarn upgrade react-native-gesture-handler
...

cd ios/
pod update
```